# adding lines in C code using Python script

Tags: python, c

I need to calculate the execution time of a loop in C code and for that i need to write a python script that adds "gettimeofday" before and after the loop by detecting the comments before and after the loop.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i,j;
  int M = argv[0][0] * 10000;
  int res = argc; 

  // loopId = 1; depth = 1; outermost
  for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
    // loopId = 2; depth = 2; innermost 
    for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
      res *= 7 % 71;
    }     
    // end loop (loopId = 2)
    // loopId = 3; depth = 2; innermost
    for (j=0; j<M; j++){ 
      res += 9 % 91;
    }
    // end loop (loopId = 3)
  }
  // end loop (loopId = 1)

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Is it required to do it in Python? Because this can be done very easily in C or is the Python bit intended as an exercise? Also, what do you mean by "detecting the comments before and after the loop", aren't you going to embed C in Python? As this sounds like you're going to parse the C text file using Python.

Comment: Why not just use `clock()` in C?

Comment: @Nobilis: I'm pretty sure she wants to write a script that _edits the C source code_. Which is easy to do in Python, and hard to do in C.

Comment: @abarnert aha, this makes more sense, because it would have been odd to attempt to measure a loop in a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys, re

expS=re.compile(r'\s*//\s*loopId = (\d+); depth = \d+; \w+')
expE=re.compile(r'\s*//\s*end loop \(loopId = (\d+)\)')
lines, varcnt = [], 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        lines += [ line ]
        m = re.match(expS, line)
        if m:
            varcnt += 1
            loopid = int(m.group(1))
            lines += [ 'gettimeofday(&tv[{}], 0);'.format((loopid-1)*2) ]
            continue
        m = re.match(expE, line)
        if m:
            loopid = int(m.group(1))
            sid, eid = (loopid-1)*2, (loopid-1)*2+1
            lines += [ 'gettimeofday(&tv[{}], 0);'.format(eid) ]
            lines += [ 'printf("Id {}: %ld\\n", tdiff_xxx(&tv[{}],&tv[{}]));'.format(
                loopid, sid, eid) ]

print '#include <sys/time.h>'
print 'struct timeval tv[{}];'.format(varcnt*2)
print 'long tdiff_xxx(struct timeval *t0, struct timeval *t1) {'
print '  return (t1->tv_sec-t0->tv_sec)*1000000 + t1->tv_usec-t0->tv_usec;'
print '}' 
for l in lines: print l
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic idea for any code-transforming tool is simple:

Iterate through the source line by line (or token by token, or whatever's appropriate—but given your sample, lines are fine). Copy the lines to a new file, also adding in whatever new lines are added, and keeping track of any information you'll need later.

Here's the skeleton to use:

```
rloop = re.compile(r'…')
rendloop = re.compile(r'…')

with open('old.c') as oldc, open('new.c', 'w') as newc:
    loops = {}
    for line in c:
        mloop = rloop.match(line.strip())
        if mloop:
            loops[m.groups(1)] = m.groups()
            newc.write(appropriate start-of-loop code)
        newc.write(line)
        mendloop = rendloop.match(line.strip())
        if mendloop:
            matching_start = loops[m.groups(1)]
            newc.write(appropriate end-of-loop code)
```

That should be enough to get you started. If you have specific questions, do what you can, and ask a specific question.

If you don't know how to use regular expressions, you can replace the `rloop.match` calls with explicit string-parsing code; it'll just be a bit more verbose.

Comment: this is kinda of bad advice. Why not use a real parser (like [pycparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser)) ?

Comment: it's kinda of exercise and the aim is to parse the c text file and add directely in the c file the required lines to measure a loop (i have to use gettimeofday).

Comment: the comments before and after every loop are added in purpose so that i replace it by gettimeofday

Comment: @JBernardo: Why use a real parser? The input is specifically designed so that each line is either a comment to be handled, or a line of code to be left untouched. A full parser would be overkill, and an invitation for bugs. On top of that, if you parse the code and re-generate it from an AST, you have to keep track of whitespace, etc., with all of C's fiddly rules; if you don't re-generate the source from the AST, you're just using it to drive line-by-line rules anyway, so what does it add?